# WMIC file copy from server to a client fails

Tags: networking, path, wmic

I try to run from a server the following command but it doesn't finally works. What I try to do is to copy a file from the c$ of my server to a specific client.

10.10.10.10  (The server)

10.10.10.100 (A client)

NOT WORKING

```
wmic /node:10.10.10.100 /USER:"administrator@test.local" /PASSWORD:"ppaass" process call create "XCOPY /Y \\10.10.10.10\c$\script\a.txt c:\a.txt*"
```

Result in command prompt

```
Executing (Win32_Process)->Create()
Method execution successful.
Out Parameters:
instance of __PARAMETERS
{
        ProcessId = 1132;
        ReturnValue = 0;
};
```

WORKING Command

```
wmic /node:10.10.10.100 /USER:"administrator@test.local" /PASSWORD:"ppaass" process call create "cmd.exe /c 'type c:\a.txt > c:\b.txt"
```

What might be wrong in the first command?

Answer (score 0):

The "results" for the non-working version are actually telling you things DID work (return of code 0 means "successful").  But all it's telling you is that the "process call create" call worked.

That reports it's running your process, so most likely the command you called (XCopy) is failing for some reason.

My guess would be that the user that's use to launch the process on the client doesn't have access to the Admin shares (`c$`) on the server.  OR it's because you're trying to copy the file into the root of C: which is generally not allowed in Windows versions newer than XP.

To debug, log onto the client as the user you're trying to use to launch the command, run it manually in a command-prompt, and note the results/error messages.

And/or extend the command your trying to fire by WMI to include redirection of the StdOut and StdErr output streams to a file.   Something like:

`XCOPY /Y \\10.10.10.10\c$\script\a.txt c:\a.txt 1> c:\output.txt 2>&1`

And then examine `output.txt`'s contents.

(again, unlike as written in this example, try to avoid using the root of C: to hold files, make a folder and target stuff there).

Comment: The XCopy command runs properly from the client's command prompt with admin credentials. The other think I thought is to run a `net use` command with the above way but it also failed.